# Why isn't my array outputting the correct data, which was input from an external file?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, character

I seem to be having trouble with my array output when the input is from a textfile... Though the output is supposed to be a single character (A,B,C,D) the array outputs gibberish, symbols like @, ?, etc. when prompted. Any sort of help would be appreciated. The grade part of the program isn't calculating either, but I can figure that out myself.  the program compiles and runs with the errors being:

```
29  46  C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\bob project\Proj1.cpp   [Warning] deprecated           
conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

and the same error for line 32

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Global constants
const int SIZE = 20;    // The number of questions
const int numQuestions = 20;
// Function prototypes
void readFile(char filename[],char answers[], int SIZE);
void compareAnswers(char student[], char correct[], int SIZE, int & numMissed);
void displayTestResults(int numMissed, int SIZE);

int main()
{
    // Number of questions missed.
    int numMissed;

// Array to hold the correct answers
char correct[SIZE];

// Array to hold the student's answers
char student[SIZE];

//Read the correct answers.
readFile("CorrectAnswers.txt", correct, SIZE);

    // Read the student's answers.
readFile("StudentAnswers.txt", student, SIZE);

// Compare the student's answers with the correct
// answers.
compareAnswers(student, correct, SIZE, numMissed);

// Display the test results.
displayTestResults(numMissed, SIZE);
   system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

// ********************************************************
// The readFile function reads the contents of an answer  *
// file into an array.                                    *
// ********************************************************
void readFile(char filename[], char values[], int SIZE)
{

fstream inFile;

// Open the file.
inFile.open(filename);
for (char i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
inFile>>values[i];
inFile.close();
}
return;
}

// ********************************************************
// The compareAnswers function compares the elements of   *
// the student array with the elements of the correct     *
// array. For each student answer that is incorrect the   *
// funcction increments a counter that keeps track of the *
// number of incorrect answers, making this available via *
// a call by reference argument.  The function displays   *
// the question number answered incorrectly along with    *
// answer given by the student and the correct answer.    *
// ********************************************************
void compareAnswers(char student[], char correct[],
                int SIZE, int &numMissed)
{
// Initialize numMissed.
numMissed = 0;

cout<< "Checking the answers...\n";

// Step through the answer arrays comparing
// each answer.
for (char i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){


  if(student[i] == correct[i])
  {i++;}



  else
  {
    numMissed++;
    cout<<"I'm sorry, you had the wrong answer for "<<i + 1<<"."<<endl;
    cout<<"Your answer was "<<student[i]<<".";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"The correct answer was "<<correct[i]<<".";
    i++;
    cin.ignore();
  }
}


return;
}

// ********************************************************
// The displayTestResults function displays the test      *
// statistics.                                            *
// ********************************************************   
void displayTestResults(int numMissed, int SIZE)
{ 
int temp;

    // Calculate the number of correctly answered
// questions.
int correctlyAnswered = SIZE - numMissed;

// Calculate the numeric score correctly rounded to the nearest tenth of a percent.
temp == static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(correctlyAnswered/SIZE*10+0.5));
// Display the number of correctly answered
// questions.
cout<<" The number of questions you got correct is:" <<correctlyAnswered;
// Display the percentage of correctly
// answered questions.
cout<<" The percentage of questions you got correct is:"<<temp;
//Display the letter grade on the exam.

cout<<endl<<endl;
if (temp >=93)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is an: A";}
else if(temp>=89)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is an: A-";}
else if(temp>=87)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: B+";}
else if(temp>=83)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: B";}
else if(temp>=79)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: B-";}
else if(temp>=77)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: C+";}
else if(temp>=73)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: C";}
else if(temp>=69)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: C-";}
else if(temp>=67)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: D+";}
else if(temp>=63)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: D";}
else if(temp>=57)
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: D-";}
else
{cout<<"Your letter grade is a: F"<<endl;}

return;
`enter code here`}
```

Comment: Which line is the error line?  I'm not going to count.

Comment: Don't do `i++` inside the `for` loop, you're already doing that in the head of the loop.

Comment: @nhgrif this is line 29:readFile("CorrectAnswers.txt", correct, SIZE);

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I'll fix that now

Comment: In regards to what @Barmar is talking about, replace `{i++;}` with `continue;` or simply `//nothing to do here`

Comment: Change the parameter declaration in `readFile` to `const char filename[]`

Comment: Pretty much everything about this line is wrong: `void readFile(char filename[], char values[], int SIZE)`, which is why you are getting error when you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To silence the warnings, the function should be declared as:

```
void readFile(const char *filename, char *answers, int SIZE)
```

It's complaining because you're passing a string literal, which is constant, to a function that doesn't declare the argument as const.

To solve the gibberish, change the body of the for loop to:

```
if(student[i] != correct[i]) {
    numMissed++;
    cout<<"I'm sorry, you had the wrong answer for "<<i + 1<<"."<<endl;
    cout<<"Your answer was "<<student[i]<<".";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"The correct answer was "<<correct[i]<<".";
    cin.ignore();
}
```

You don't need to do `i++` inside the loop, it's already being done in the loop header.

Comment: The use of SIZE as a parameter name in the function is also confusing as OP uses it as a constant throughout the pgm. "size" would be better.

Comment: That's true, but if I put that in my answer I'll have to rewrite the entire program, since he does that in all his functions.

Comment: It's not necessary to change your answer which got to the point.  The comment was more of style note to OP.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your help! The errors have gone away, unfortunately I'm still getting gibberish for output.

Comment: Where is the gibberish? Maybe the contents of the input file aren't what you think.

Comment: @Barmar
    cout<<"Your answer was "<<student[i]<<".";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"The correct answer was "<<correct[i]<<".";
    cin.ignore();

The gibberish is outputtted where the answer should be.  The input file is just a list of letters my professor gave me.  I talked to my other classmates and they are having the same problem so it seems that it is the input file we were given which is causing the error. Thanks for your help!